# Override Rails date_select form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to override the date_select form helper in my app (running Rails 3.2), to bring in the `:selected` parameter from the [Rails 4 date_select](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1dd89250d12aba01d605af270201371e5cec89a4/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/date_select.rb#L30).

[Overriding default Rails date_select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007675/overriding-default-rails-date-select) is a little old now, but I was referencing this to try to make it work.

So I have the following in a file in `lib/`, included at the bottom of `environment.rb`:

```
ActionView::Helpers::Tags::DateSelect.class_eval do
#
# Note: Using ActionView::Helpers::DateTimeSelector as suggested in 
# linked question doesn't error, but also doesn't seem to do anything.
#
  def datetime_selector(options, html_options)
    datetime = options[:selected] || value(object) || default_datetime(options)
    @auto_index ||= nil

    options = options.dup
    options[:field_name]           = @method_name
    options[:include_position]     = true
    options[:prefix]             ||= @object_name
    options[:index]                = @auto_index if @auto_index && !options.has_key?(:index)

    DateTimeSelector.new(datetime, options, html_options)
  end

end
```

However when trying to start my app, I see:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::Tags
```

This is confirmed when playing in the console:

```
1.9.3-p327 :001 > ActionView
 => ActionView 
1.9.3-p327 :002 > ActionView::Helpers
 => ActionView::Helpers 
1.9.3-p327 :003 > ActionView::Helpers::Tags
NameError: uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::Tags
  from (irb):3
  from /Users/colin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
  from /Users/colin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
  from /Users/colin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

So, why isn't `ActionView::Helpers::Tags` valid, when that is where the class is defined, and how do I override the class properly to override the datetime_selector method?

---

**Answer**

After Dan pointed out that I was trying to monkey-patch the wrong file, the solution was fairly straight forward - this code does the job (placed in an initializer):

```
ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag.class_eval do
  def datetime_selector(options, html_options)
    datetime = options.fetch(:selected) { value(object) || default_datetime(options) }

    @auto_index ||= nil

    options = options.dup
    options[:field_name]           = @method_name
    options[:include_position]     = true
    options[:prefix]             ||= @object_name
    options[:index]                = @auto_index if @auto_index && !options.has_key?(:index)

    ActionView::Helpers::DateTimeSelector.new(datetime, options, html_options)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActionView::Helpers::Tags` is new in Rails 4 (you link to the rails master branch, which is the 4.0 branch), where you are working on a Rails 3.2.x app, you need to look at the source code for that 3.2stable branch. This looks like the place to monkey patch [date_select](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L220)

Comment: I was convinced I'd seen that same file in 3.2 - been digging through too much code! Thanks.