# Override date_select helper to add start_year and end_year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to add :start_year and :end_year to my date_select helper. What is the way to extend date_select helper to add it by default so that I don't have to change hundreds of views.

In short I have following in my view:

```
    <li><%= f.label :hire_date %><%= f.date_select :hire_date %></li>
```

I want to have the following:

```
    <li><%= f.label :hire_date %><%= f.date_select :hire_date, :start_year=>1950 , :end_year=>2050%></li>
```

So how can I extend the date_select so that I don't have to make this change in all my views.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359097/override-rails-date-select-form-helper

Answer (score 0):

Following code in file name date_select.rb in config/initializers did the trick:

```
ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper.class_eval do
      def date_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})
        start_year = 1950
        end_year = 2050
        options[:start_year] = start_year
        options[:end_year] = end_year
        ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag.new(object_name, method, self, options.delete(:object)).to_date_select_tag(options, html_options)
      end
end
```